# null cannot be cast to non-null type com.example.kotlindiary.MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin

Внутри фрагмента в главной активности при загрузке данных из FireBase проверяется, все ли необходимые данные имеет пользователь, если нет, то он отсылается к необходимой активности для ввода данных. Когда пользователь попадает в необходимую активити, он может переключаться между различными активити для ввода различной информации (школа->класс->расписание)

И почему-то в активити со школами при выборе школы, выскакивает ошибка, которая находится во фрагменте главной активити.

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.example.kotlindiary.MainActivity
        at com.example.kotlindiary.MainFragment$downloadHomework$1$onDataChange$1.onDataChange(MainFragment.kt:210)
```

Жалуется на строчку с инициализацией Intent:

```
if(timetableisreal){...}
else{
    val intent = Intent(activity, SetTimetableActivity::class.java)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Отмечу, что ошибка выскакивает именно при выборе школы, а ошибка отсылается к главному фрагменту. У меня есть предположение, что ValueEventListener прогоняет этот код несколько раз и в этот момент выходит ошибка. Но тогда странно, что после завершения работы главной активности, слушатель продолжает работу. Заранее спасибо

UPD: код фрагмента

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {
        ...
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        ...
        downloadHomework()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    fun downloadHomework(){
        ...
        ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                user = p0.getValue(User::class.java)
                val schoolName = user?.school
                val form = user?.form
                if(user?.name == "" || user?.surname == ""){//проверка, есть ли имя, фамилия
                    val intent = Intent(activity, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    (activity as MainActivity).finish()
                }
                else if(schoolName == ""){//выбрана ли школа
                    val intent = Intent(activity, ChooseSchoolActivity::class.java)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

                    startActivity(intent)
                    (activity as MainActivity).finish()
                }
                else if(form == ""){//выбран ли класс
                    val intent = Intent(activity, ChooseFormActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("schoolName", schoolName)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    (activity as MainActivity).finish()
                }
                else{
                    val refTimetable = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/schools/$schoolName/$form/timetable")
                    refTimetable.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                            p0.children.forEach {
                                //проверка, есть ли расписание
                            }
                            if(timetableisreal){...}
                            else{
                                val intent = Intent(activity, SetTimetableActivity::class.java)//если нет, отправляем на активити с установкой расписания
                                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                                startActivity(intent)
                            }

                        }
                        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
                    })
                }

            }
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: В каком методе вызывается val intent = Intent(activity?

Comment: Внутри фунуции downloadHomework, который находится вне class MainFragment

Comment: ЮрийСПБ, ошибка, функция находится внутри class MainFragment

Comment: @ЮрийСПб для уведомления

Comment: Покажите фрагмент целиком. Вообще я имел в виду метод жизненного цикла.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вызывается в onviewcreated, код фрагмента добавил в вопросе

Comment: Скорее всего ваши предположения верны. Попробуйте вынести оба `object : ValueEventListener` в отдельные переменные и перед переходом в другие активити явно отписываться от изменений примерно так: `ref.removeValueEventListener(переменнаяОписаннаяВыше)`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это сработало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши предположения оказались верны. Слушатель изменений в удалённой БД продолжает реагировать на изменения в ней даже после покидания активити. В итоге активити и становится null, когда идёт к ней обращение.

Чтобы этого избежать, вам надо явно отписываться от изменений в БД. Для этого сохраните ваш слушатель в отдельную переменную и перед покиданием активити - удалите его. Примерно так:

```
val listener = object : ValueEventListener ...
ref.addValueEventListener(listener)

ref.removeValueEventListener(listener)
```